# Change SVG image path with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I am not very familiar with SVG and wonder how I could change the path with jQuery.

My image is loaded like this in HTML:

```
<img id="img-nav-about" src="/assets/images/common/img_nav_about.svg" alt="About">
```

I try to change the src attribute with jQuery like this:

```
$("#img-nav-about").attr("src","/assets/images/FR/common/img_nav_about.svg");
```

Somehow this line of code doesn't work with SVG files (it does with jpg, png, etc.), so I assume I have to do something extra to make it work...

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try using prop() instead of attr(), but it should work as it is. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with the SVG file instead. I tried to use another SVG image from wikipedia just to test and it works.

Comment: That must surely be the problem then

Comment: Thanks for helping! At least I know that it's supposed to work.